# Firebird OR Operator Usage with Nested Condition

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm not very familiar with Firebird., maybe someone can clarify some basics for me.

I have a fairly simple query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "PREORDER"
WHERE COLLECTED = 'N'
AND MOST_RECENT = 'Y'
```

I want to select all elements that have the Collected Boolean on N and are most Recent. But I also would want to select all elements that are collected and have a customer number unequal to zero. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "PREORDER"
WHERE ( COLLECTED = 'N' OR (COLLECTED = 'Y' AND (CUSTOMER_NUMBER <> 0 ) ) )
AND MOST_RECENT = 'Y'
```

Of course, I am not getting the syntax right here, maybe someone could explain me on how to properly express this.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is designed to be close to natural English so to get needed expression we can simply reduce this sentence into actions:

> I want to select all elements that have the Collected Bolean on N and
> are most Recent. But i also would want o select all elements where
> that are collected and have a customer number unequal to zero.

> Collected on N and are most Recent

```
Collected = 'N' and Most_Recent = 'Y'
```

> also

```
OR
```

> collected and have a customer number unequal to zero

```
Collected = 'Y' and Customer_Number <> 0
```

Overall result:

```
Select * from Preorder
where (Collected = 'N' and Most_Recent = 'Y') OR (Collected = 'Y' and Customer_Number <> 0)
```

Comment: The parentheses are not necessary here as `AND` has a higher priority than `OR`.

Comment: I never was able to remember all operations' priorities across languages so I use brackets for readability even if they are unnecessary. It won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing

```sql
WHERE ( COLLECTED = 'N' OR (COLLECTED = 'Y' AND (CUSTOMER_NUMBER <> 0 ) ) )
```

Comment: You have left out your `MOST_RECENT = 'Y'` condition. Also, you don't need all those parentheses.